# Refactor (DRY, KISS) QueryStatus event for VS Addin

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have complex logic in QueryStatus event (CommandTarget) for a VS Addin (VS 2010).

I'm a newbie using C#.

I would like elegant, easily maintainable code that follows DRY and KISS principles. Maybe using helper with ActionT> or FuncT> methods.

There are many **commands** to use: using `if` statements and `switch` statements.

Main method: `QueryStatus` event call to **comandosOracleNET** method.

**comandosOracleNET** method determines if a option in Menu is visible or not.

```
  void IDTCommandTarget.QueryStatus(string CmdName, vsCommandStatusTextWanted NeededText, ref vsCommandStatus StatusOption, ref object CommandText)
        {
            if (!OnStartupCompleted) return;

            try
            {
                if (NeededText == vsCommandStatusTextWanted.vsCommandStatusTextWantedNone)
                {

                    comandosOracleNET(CmdName, NeededText, ref StatusOption, ref CommandText);

                    return;

                }


            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                ErroresManager.TratamientoExcepcionEnConnectQueryStatus(exc, "Error en Command. Excepción en IDTCommandTarget.QueryStatus.");
            }

        }
```

Main method:

```
private void comandosOracleNET(string CmdName, vsCommandStatusTextWanted NeededText, ref vsCommandStatus StatusOption, ref object CommandText)
{
    EnvDTE80.Solution2 solucion = (EnvDTE80.Solution2)_applicationObject.Solution;
    string etiqueta = null;
    bool bajoSC = false;

    if (_applicationObject.SourceControl != null
        && _applicationObject.Solution != null
        && _applicationObject.Solution.IsOpen
        && !solucion.FullName.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()
        && _applicationObject.SourceControl.IsItemUnderSCC(solucion.FullName))
    {
        etiqueta = Logica.OperacionesEtiquetado.ObtenerEtiquetaSolucion(solucion);
        bajoSC = true;
    }


       #region Branch y Merge

        if  (CmdName == _addInInstance.ProgID + "." + ComandoBranchItemSqlForSW_Name)
        {
            if (_applicationObject.SelectedItems.Count == 1 && _applicationObject.SelectedItems.Item(1).ProjectItem.FileCount == 1)
            {
                string aux = _applicationObject.SelectedItems.Item(1).ProjectItem.get_FileNames(1);
                if (aux.ToLower().EndsWith(".sql"))
                {
                    StatusOption = vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported | vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled;
                }
                else
                {
                    StatusOption |= vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusInvisible;
                }
            }
            return;
        }

        if (CmdName == _addInInstance.ProgID + "." + ComandoMergeItemSqlForSW_Name)
        {
            if (_applicationObject.SelectedItems.Count == 1 && _applicationObject.SelectedItems.Item(1).ProjectItem.FileCount == 1)
            {
                string aux = _applicationObject.SelectedItems.Item(1).ProjectItem.get_FileNames(1);
                if (aux.ToLower().EndsWith(".sql"))
                {
                    StatusOption = vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported | vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled;
                }
                else
                {
                    StatusOption |= vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusInvisible;
                }
            }
            return;
        }
        #endregion


  switch (CmdName)
            {

                case ComandoLogsPorEtiqueta:
                    if (solucion.IsOpen
                        && solucion.Projects.Count > 0
                        && bajoSC
                        && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(etiqueta))
                    {
                        StatusOption = vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported | vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        StatusOption |= vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusInvisible;
                    }
                    break;

                case ComandoLogsPorSolucion:
                    if (solucion.IsOpen && bajoSC
                        && solucion.Projects.Count > 0)
                    {
                        StatusOption = vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported | vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        StatusOption |= vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusInvisible;
                    }
                    break;

                case "AddIn.Connect.Etiquetar":
                    if (bajoSC && solucion.IsOpen &&
                        solucion.Projects.Count > 0 &&
                        _applicationObject.SourceControl.IsItemUnderSCC(solucion.FileName) &&
                        String.IsNullOrEmpty(etiqueta))
                    {
                        StatusOption = vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported | vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        StatusOption |= vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusInvisible;
                    }
                    break;


                case "AddIn.Connect.VisualizarMFA":
                    if (_applicationObject.SelectedItems.Count == 1 && _applicationObject.SelectedItems.Item(1).ProjectItem.FileCount == 1)
                    {
                        string aux = _applicationObject.SelectedItems.Item(1).ProjectItem.get_FileNames(1);
                        if (aux.ToLower().EndsWith(".mfa"))
                        {
                            StatusOption = vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported | vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            StatusOption |= vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusInvisible;
                        }
                    }

                case "AddIn.Connect.Consola":
                case "AddIn.Connect.Despliegue":
                    StatusOption = vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported;
                    if (!solucion.IsOpen)
                    {
                        StatusOption |= vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusInvisible;
                        return;
                    }
                    object[] prjs = (object[])_applicationObject.ActiveSolutionProjects;
                    Project pj = null;

                    if (prjs.Length != 1)
                    {
                        StatusOption |= vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusInvisible;
                        return;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pj = (Project)prjs[0];
                    }

                    if (trackMFAProjects.ContainsKey(pj.UniqueName))
                    {
                        if (trackMFAProjects[pj.UniqueName])
                        {
                            StatusOption |= vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            StatusOption |= vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusInvisible;
                        }

                        return;
                    }

                    if (Logica.Operaciones.IsMFAProject(pj))
                    {
                        trackMFAProjects[pj.UniqueName] = true;
                        StatusOption |= vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled;
                        Logica.Operaciones.IniciarProyecto(pj);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        trackMFAProjects[pj.UniqueName] = false;
                        StatusOption |= vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusInvisible;
                    }

                    break;
                #endregion

                case ComandoDespliegueSqlServer:
                    StatusOption = vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported;
                    if (!solucion.IsOpen)
                    {
                        StatusOption |= vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusInvisible;
                        return;
                    }
                    object[] proyectos = (object[])_applicationObject.ActiveSolutionProjects;
                    Project proyecto = null;

                    if (proyectos.Length != 1)
                    {
                        StatusOption |= vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusInvisible;
                        return;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        proyecto = (Project)proyectos[0];
                    }

                    if (Logica.Operaciones.IsDeploySqlServerProject(proyecto))
                    {
                        StatusOption |= vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        StatusOption |= vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusInvisible;
                    }

                    break;



                // much source code not shown, several case options...


 default:

                    if (CmdName == _addInInstance.ProgID + "." + NamedCommandDebugView
                        || CmdName == _addInInstance.ProgID + "." + NamedCommandAbrirLogsVisualStudio
                        || CmdName == _addInInstance.ProgID + "." + NamedCommandAbrirAyuda)
                    {
                        StatusOption = vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported | vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled;
                        return;
                    }

                    if (QueryStatusHelper(CmdName, NeededText, ref StatusOption, ref CommandText)) return;

                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Comando desconocido recibido: " + CmdName);
                    StatusOption = vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusUnsupported;
                    break;
            }
            #endregion

            return;
        }
```

Any suggestions?

I'm starting like this in `BranchMergeManager` class:

```
 public static void QueryBranch(DTE2 app, ref vsCommandStatus StatusOption)
    {
        if (app.SelectedItems.Count != 1 || app.SelectedItems.Item(1).ProjectItem.FileCount != 1) return;

        string aux = app.SelectedItems.Item(1).ProjectItem.get_FileNames(1);
        if (aux.ToLower().EndsWith(".sql"))
        {
            StatusOption = vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported | vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled;
            return;
        }

        StatusOption |= vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusInvisible;
    }
```

Comment: I believe that it's best practice to have english variables and comments even though the software and the developers are spanish speaking. Please check: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/113936/is-it-a-good-practice-to-code-in-english?lq=1 for a rationale.

Comment: @Vogel612 Full source code added for **comandosOracleNET()** . There are commands in VS Addin. Updated question.

Answer (score 5):

Using [`#region`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a1ybwek.aspx) in a method is a very strong indicator that the method should be broken into smaller methods. [It is considered as code smell.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/53086/100919)

---

You have to much vertical spacing (new lines) in your code so **Sam the Maintainer** can't grasp the code at first glance.

---

Using braces `{}` for single `if` statements is a good start to make your code less error prone. If you consider to not use them, you should stick to your style you choose. Right now you are mixing them.

---

Using the english language for naming variables will help **Sam the Maintainer** to maintain the code if he/she doesn't speak your language.

While we are at the naming of variables, based on the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) input parameters should be named using `camelCase` casing.

---

A `if..else` like

```
if (condition) 
{
    // some code
    return;
}
else
{
    //some other code
}
```

makes the `else` part redundant, you can simplify this to

```
if (condition) 
{
    // some code
    return;
}
//some other code
```

---

By using a second guard clause in the `IDTCommandTarget.QueryStatus()` method, you can reduce the horizintal spacing which add readability to your code.

The `return` statement in the `try..catch` is redundant and should be removed.

```
void IDTCommandTarget.QueryStatus(string cmdName, vsCommandStatusTextWanted neededText, ref vsCommandStatus statusOption, ref object commandText)
{
    if (!OnStartupCompleted) { return; }
    if (neededText != vsCommandStatusTextWanted.vsCommandStatusTextWantedNone) { return; }

    try
    {
        comandosOracleNET(cmdName, neededText, ref statusOption, ref commandText);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        ErroresManager.TratamientoExcepcionEnConnectQueryStatus(exc, "Error en Command. Excepción en IDTCommandTarget.QueryStatus.");
    }
}
```

---

By extracting the if statements of `#region Branch y Merge` to a separate method you can reduce code duplication.

```
private bool IsBrancheOrMerge(String cmdName)
{
    return (cmdName == _addInInstance.ProgID + "." + ComandoBranchItemSqlForSW_Name) ||
           (cmdName == _addInInstance.ProgID + "." + ComandoMergeItemSqlForSW_Name);
}
```

now the former 2 `if` statements can be reduced to

```
if(IsBrancheOrMerge(cmdName))
{
    if (_applicationObject.SelectedItems.Count == 1 && _applicationObject.SelectedItems.Item(1).ProjectItem.FileCount == 1)
    {
        string aux = _applicationObject.SelectedItems.Item(1).ProjectItem.get_FileNames(1);
        if (aux.ToLower().EndsWith(".sql"))
        {
            StatusOption = vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported | vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled;
        }
        else
        {
            StatusOption |= vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusInvisible;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

and by extracting the inner `if` statements to a method `ProcessBranchOrMerge()`

```
private void ProcessBranchOrMerge(ref vsCommandStatus statusOption)
{
    if (_applicationObject.SelectedItems.Count == 1 && _applicationObject.SelectedItems.Item(1).ProjectItem.FileCount == 1)
    {
        string aux = _applicationObject.SelectedItems.Item(1).ProjectItem.get_FileNames(1);
        if (aux.ToLower().EndsWith(".sql"))
        {
            statusOption = vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported | vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled;
        }
        else
        {
            statusOption |= vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusInvisible;
        }
    }
}
```

it can be further reduced to

```
if(IsBrancheOrMerge(cmdName))
{
    ProcessBranchOrMerge(ref statusOption);
    return;
}
```

In a similiar way you can extract more of your code to separate methods.

**case ComandoDespliegueSqlServer:**

This case can be easily extracted to a improved method like

```
private void ProcessComandoDespliegueSqlServer(ref vsCommandStatus statusOption, EnvDTE80.Solution2 solucion)
{
    statusOption = vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported | vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusInvisible;

    if (!solucion.IsOpen) { return; }

    object[] proyectos = (object[])_applicationObject.ActiveSolutionProjects;

    if (proyectos.Length != 1) { return; }

    if (Logica.Operaciones.IsDeploySqlServerProject((Project)proyectos[0]))
    {
        statusOption |= vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled;
    }
}
```

leaving the `case`

```
case ComandoDespliegueSqlServer:
    ProcessComandoDespliegueSqlServer(ref statusOption, solucion);
    return;
```